# How do I get SocketCluster to restart on file change?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socketcluster

I'm running http://socketcluster.io/ and I want to restart my workers whewnever a file changes.  However, `nodemon server.js` fails as soon as it tries to restart with an endlessly-repeating wall of:

```
1445633138359 - Origin: Worker (PID 44372)
    [Error] Error: connect ECONNREFUSED /var/folders/fj/yzfd3_tn7xd0smz7j6s093mh0000gn/T/socketcluster/6879fe94-ed92-4188-b1d7-cb187a5ade4e_b68fcded6c/b0
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:897:20)
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
1445633138362 - Worker 0 exited - Exit code: 0
```

How can I safely restart SocketCluster to load the new changes?

Comment: PM2 will let you restart upon file changes with no downtime if you use clustering.

Comment: the ECONNREFUSED is because your child processes were not killed correctly, something else PM2 can help avoid.

Comment: @dandavis Does that work with SocketCluster in particular?  It has its own clustering mechanism.

Comment: not sure about that specifically, but PM2 can handle things besides node, so "probably" if i had to guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nodemon` sends the `SIGUSR2` signal to the main (Master) process.  SocketCluster (correctly) interprets this as as a request to reboot the workers.  Unfortunately, there's an [open issue](https://github.com/SocketCluster/socketcluster/issues/108) where things are not shut down properly and errors fly all around.

There are two options:

You can add the code from the linked issue:

```
house.addShutdownHandler(function(ctx, next){
    socketCluster.killWorkers();
    socketCluster.killBrokers();
    next();
});
```

or use [`forever`](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) to send a "restart everything" signal:

```
forever -w --killSignal=SIGTERM server.js
```

Comment: Hi .. where exactly would one implement this? is this a patch i'd need to specify in the sc code itself? I'm confused over the `house` variable used

Answer (score 0):

Improvements were made for nodemon in SC version 5.0.23 or later.

Make sure that you pass `killMasterOnSignal: true` when instantiating SocketCluster in your code (server.js file) - This setting is necessary for nodemon to work.